# Windows Active Directory monitoring with zabbix

Tags: active-directory, devops, monitoring, zabbix

I want to monitor my Windows Active Directory with the Zabbix and want to collect data of users, sessions, logs, etc.

How can I achieve this because I am not able to find any supporting document to configure AD in Zabbix. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into "Zabbix Integrations", [here](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/active_directory) you can find a ready template with these checks:

> Check windows event log: * Create user account * User account on *
> User account off * User account password reset * Delete user account *
> Unlocked user account + changed domain policy and cleaned security log

You can extend it with your own checks (i.e.: powershell scripts).

Comment: Do I need to configure LDAP first to achieve this?

Comment: In the page it says "Zabbix Agent Active" and the template uses the `eventlog` items,so I guess you'll need to install the agent on your domain controller and enable logging for the defined events... and for any other event you want to capture.